# how to get recordStats in mongodb 3.2?

Tags: mongodb

I want to monitor `accessNotInMemory` of mongodb, before I can use

```
db.adminCommand({'serverStatus': 1})['recordStats']
```

but according to [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/),

> Changed in version 3.0: serverStatus no longer outputs the workingSet, indexCounters, and recordStats sections.

how can I get the recordStats in mongodb 3.2?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to monitor accessNotInMemory of mongodb

The database-level `recordStats` information was specific to the older MMAP storage engine and removed during the MongoDB 3.0 development cycle as part of the work toward collection-level locking and the new storage engine API.

A more general performance indicator you can monitor is [`db.serverStatus().extra_info.page_faults`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverstatus.extra_info.page_faults). This metric is available in MongoDB 3.2 as well as prior versions (2.2+, at least).

Given there are multiple storage engines available in MongoDB 3.0, there are also more detailed per-engine metrics that might be of interest. For example, WiredTiger is the default storage engine as at MongoDB 3.2, and includes a comprehensive set of metrics in the [`wiredTiger`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#wiredtiger) section of `serverStatus` output.